# Autowiring or setter injection

Tags: spring, autowired

So far, in our project, we have got our beans having the references set through setter injections; recently, couple of people have started to use @Autowired annotation to set the references on their beans; is it a good to mix annotations and xml configurations for context?

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. In our project we have a mix of these two. Some old code still uses xml bases setters but new once are using annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing annotations and XML definitions works pretty well to reduce amount of code in XML file.

Certainly you can have both coexisting; XML definitions will always override any annotations in Java code without causing a trouble.

Is it good or bad?? I think it's just a way to balance size of an XML file. I find very useful to define my beans in a simple way in XML and then just use `@Autowire` annotation including `@Required` to ensure bean has been properly injected before been used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using the two together but better to choose one for consistency sake. It would be easier for all the developers to understand and maintain the code.

My preference is annotations as I like things defined at one place.